# DDOS Атака или нет? Как понять?

Tags: ddos

Как отличить DDoS-атаку, например, от эффекта рекламной кампании?

Comment: По количеству заказов :)

Comment: @Khipster  Тоже вариант :)

Comment: хороший вопрос кстати Но все равно как не  крути все равно ухищряются DDOS- ить. Нету какой нибудь системы для предотвращения.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

- по айпишникам. Вряд ли у тебя РК на весь мир транслируется, а если и транслируется, ею заинтересуются в основном русскоязычные - если сайт, допустим, русскоязычный. Если же айпишники прут со всего мира, или например, из Китая, хотя у тебя нет РК для Китая - подозревай DDoS
- по юзер-агентам, если атакующий не слишком продвинут, то по ним будет паттерн виден.
- по частоте запросов с одинаковых айпишников. Человек зашел на сайт, посмотрел и ушел, бот просто флудит запросами
- и да, по аналитике твоей рекламной системы. DDOS-запросы в аналитике не будут зарегистрированы

ну и в принципе, по частоте запросов обычно видно, непрекращающийся DDoS трафик выглядит иначе, чем заходы людей на сайт на любом графике